# Web-to-lead form with File Upload using lwc

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, web2lead

I am trying to create a web-to-lead form with LWC since I'm new to LWC.
I am not sure how to create an LWC web-to-lead form with File upload(found a package but they have done using it Screen Flow, aura)

So the requirement is to have a lead form ON A WRODPRESS site with a "Submit & Schedule a Meeting" button with it!

I have gone through a few basic data entry forms using lwc, not sure how to proceed!
Or do I need a apex in it!?

Answer (score 1):

With standard functionality it is not possible to include attachments when leads are created via web-to-lead. Salesforce’s web-to-lead form does not natively support uploading attachments.

You can implement Visualforce pages in Salesforce Sites. Check this [Salesforce official documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386429&type=1) for details.

Also in Force.com sites you can try to expose LWC component with file upload functionality. I haven't tried the file upload functionality but has exposed LWC component in Force.com Sites. You can find my answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/392333/how-to-set-lwc-on-website-homepage-in-salesforce/392338#392338).

As you have mentioned the web-to-lead form will be hosted in WRODPRESS, you can try this with WRODPRESS and PHP as mentioned in this article [Salesforce hack: web-to-lead with file upload](https://www.susannelumme.com/salesforce-hack-web-to-lead-with-file-upload/).